# How to join two table in laravel 8 with no duplicate

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have two tables. Customer and address. The relationship of the table is that a CUSTOMER can have many ADDRESSES. So what I want as a result to my query is to get the list of customer and only one latest address

```
ADDRESS TABLE
id : 1
city:"cebu"
zip_code:"600"
cus_id:1

id:2
city:"mandaue"
zip_code:"6001"
cus_id:1

CUSTOMER TABLE
id: 1
name:"JOHN DOE"
```

What I want to get the customer "JOHN DOE" and the address with ID "2"

I'm using laravel query builder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only one latest address, you can use `hasOne` same as :

```
// Customer model relation
public function lastestAddress()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'customer_id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

And

```
$model = Customer::with('lastestAddress')
```

Comment: There is also [native eloquent method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many). Added [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37362).

Comment: Ah, thank you ! I didn't read it

Answer (score 0):

you can use Eloquent ORM in laravel.

Eloquent :
You must setting in your customer model

```
Class Customer(){
public function address()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Address::class, 'cuss_id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

in your Adress model :

```
Class Address(){
public function customer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'id', 'cuss_id')
}
```

Then in your controller you can call the model :

```
$data = Customer::with('address')->get();
```

Comment: can i use a query builder?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two tables: `customers` and `addresses`, with a "one customer can have many addresses" relationship.

[image]

In Laravel, we normally use [Eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to query the database. So to get a customer and all its addresses, we must first model the database; each table with its own Eloquent model. (See details in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).)

```php
class Address extends Model
{
    // although empty for now, this class definition is still important
}
```

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the latest address.
     */
    public function currentAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'cus_id')->latestOfMany();
    }
}
```

In the `Customer` model, our `currentAddress()` method defines how a `Customer` instance related to the `Address` instances.

It's like we're saying,

> "A customer may have many `Address`es. Just get one which is the `latestOfMany`. That's how we'll get the customer's `currentAddress`.

Now that we have the necessary Eloquent models setup, we can lookup John Doe and his current address.

```php
$johnDoeId = 1;

// query the database for customer 1, including its current address
$johnDoe = Customer::with('currentAddress')->find($johnDoeId);

$johnDoe->currentAddress; //  John's latest address, at Mandaue
```